# Prolog - append to wrong list

Tags: prolog

```
temperature(thessaloniki,january,24,1).
temperature(thessaloniki,january,25,-2).
temperature(katerini,january,24,3).
temperature(loutsa,feb,25,1).

temp([],[],[]).
temp([H|T],L2,L3) :-
   temp(T,L4,L5),
   temperature(H,january,_,Te),
   Te>0,
   append([H],L4,L2),
   L3=L5.
temp([H|T],L2,L3) :-
   temp(T,L4,L5),
   temperature(H,january,25,Te),
   Te<0,
   append([H],L5,L3),
   L2=L4.
temp([H|T],L2,L3) :-
   temp(T,L4,L5),
   L2=L4,
   L3=L5.
```

We have towns with temperatures and dates. And we need to add them to the correct list. I think the rules is right but when I run it with TkEclipse I get this:

```
?- temp([thessaloniki, thessaloniki, katerini, loutsa], L2, L3).
L2 = [thessaloniki, thessaloniki, katerini]
L3 = []
```

and as I watched at the tracer of program take only the first `temperature(thessaloniki,january,24,1).` 2 times and not the second one   `temperature(thessaloniki,january,25,-2).`
 If change the name of the second to thessaloniki2 run ok but the exercise gives it with the same name.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you have once the goal `temperature(H,january,_,Te)` and once the goal `temperature(H,january,25,Te)`? I assume you mean that both should be the same goal.

But there are other stylistic remarks. I just take the first rule:

```
temp([H|T],L2,L3) :-
   temp(T,L4,L5),
   temperature(H,january,_,Te),
   Te>0,
   append([H],L4,L2),
   L3=L5.
```

`append/3` is much less used in Prolog than you might expect. You could literally replace `append([X],L4,L2)` by `L2 = [X|L4]`. But you can put it even further and move the `(=)/2`-goals to the head:

```
temp([H|T],[H|Ps],Ms) :-
   temp(T,Ps,Ms),
   temperature(H,january,_,Te),
   Te>0.
```

Not enough: A program as this, will work, but will produce an enormous overhead.  See:

- [How does recursion in Prolog works from inside. One example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14462713/how-does-recursion-in-prolog-works-from-inside-one-example/14481012#14481012)
- [Prolog - get the factors for a given number doesn't stop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14273559/prolog-get-the-factors-for-a-given-number-doesnt-stop/14288853#14288853)

In this case, move the interesting tests to the top:

```
temp([H|T],[H|Ps],Ms) :-
   temperature(H,january,_,Te),
   Te>0,
   temp(T,Ps,Ms).
```

This will avoid the exponential overhead. (Exponential in the length of the first argument's list).

The very last rule in your program should probably read: If there is no data for this city, ignore it. Thus `\+ temperature(H,january,_,_)`.

Comment: L2 list must have the names of towns at any day of january was above 0 -> temperature(H,january,_,Te) Te>0 , and L3 list name's of town's at 25 january under 0 -> temperature(H,january,25,Te) Te<0 . i use append because we didn't learn something else.

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't state clearly your goal, we are left with guessing from the code snippet. I think you're missing 'filter' values: I'll add as `Mon,Day` to enforce proper selection from declared facts.

Consider using available [control predicates](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.8%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/control.html%27%29%29), and avoid append/3:

```
temperature(thessaloniki,january,24,1).
temperature(thessaloniki,january,25,-2).
temperature(katerini,january,24,3).
temperature(loutsa,feb,25,1).

temp([H|T], Mon, Day, L2, L3) :-
   (   temperature(H, Mon, Day, Te)
   ->  (   Te > 0
       ->  L2 = [H|L4], L3 = L5
       ;   Te < 0
       ->  L2 = L4, L3 = [H|L5]
       ;   L2 = L4, L3 = L5
       )
   ;   L2 = L4, L3 = L5
   ),
   temp(T, Mon, Day, L4, L5).

temp([], _, _, [], []).
```

yields

```
?- temp([katerini, loutsa, thessaloniki],january,24,A,B).
A = [katerini, thessaloniki],
B = [].

?- temp([katerini, loutsa, thessaloniki],january,25,A,B).
A = [],
B = [thessaloniki].
```

Note how to avoid append/3: construct a list `consing` in the appropriate list 'returned' by recursive call. Thanks to Prolog unification, we can do even if the call is 'yet to come'.

I think the resulting code is tail recursive, an efficiency improvement.

HTH

*edit* Now an *equivalent* program, but (IMHO) nicer

```
temp([H|T], Mon, Day, L2, L3) :-
   (   temperature(H, Mon, Day, Te)
   ->  (   Te > 0
       ->  L2/L3 = [H|L4]/L5
       ;   Te < 0
       ->  L2/L3 = L4/[H|L5]
       ;   L2/L3 = L4/L5
       )
   ;   L2/L3 = L4/L5
   ),
   temp(T, Mon, Day, L4, L5).
```

*edit* after comments...

```
temp([H|T], L2, L3) :-
   (   temperature(H, january, Day, Te)
   ->  (   Te > 0
       ->  L2/L3 = [H|L4]/L5
       ;   Te < 0, Day = 25
       ->  L2/L3 = L4/[H|L5]
       ;   L2/L3 = L4/L5
       )
   ;   L2/L3 = L4/L5
   ),
   temp(T, L4, L5).
temp([], [], []).
```

yields

```
A = [katerini, thessaloniki],
B = [].
```

Comment: Sorry for that, i think it appears from the rules. L2 list must have the names of towns at any day of january  was above 0, and L3 list name's of town's at 25 january under 0 .

Comment: My problem is tha if you put temp([thessaloniki,thesasloniki],L2,L3). for these two events temperature(thessaloniki,january,24,1),  temperature(thessaloniki,january,25,-2). theoretically the list must be L2= thessaloniki for temperature>0 and L3=thessaloniki for temperature<0 and day==25 but the result is L2= thessaloniki,thesaloniki and L3=[] empty , and that's beacause take the first event temperature(thessaloniki,january,24,1) two times. Is there a problem because they have the same name?

Comment: Prolog make available alternatives on backtracking, so you need findall/3 or other aggregate to capture multiple values at once.

Comment: never mind i'ts my fault . i must call the predicates with only one thessaloniki and not two.                                            ?- temp([thessaloniki, katerini, loutsa], L2, L3).
L2 = [thessaloniki, katerini]
L3 = [thessaloniki] , thanks guys and i'm sorry