# Factors of a number

Tags: prolog, factors

So I am relatively new to Prolog, and while this problem is easy in many other languages I am having a lot of trouble with it. I want to generate a List of factors for a number N. I have already built a predicate that tells me if a number is a factor:

```
% A divides B
% A is a factor of B
divides(A,B) :- A =\= 0, (B mod A) =:= 0.

% special case where 1 // 2 would be 0
factors(1,[1]) :- !.

% general case
factors(N,L):- N > 0, factor_list(1, N, L).
factor_list(S,E,L) :- S =< E // 2, f_list(S,E,L).

f_list(S,E,[])    :- S > E // 2, !.
f_list(S,E,[S|T]) :- divides(S,E), !, S1 is S+1, f_list(S1, E, T).
f_list(S,E,L)     :- S1 is S+1, f_list(S1,E,L).
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

I pretty much changed my entire solution, but for some reason predicates like `factors(9, [1])` return true, when I only want `factors(9, [1,3])` to return true. Any thoughts?

Comment: if you include 1 in factors of 9, why not 9 also? Do you mean just prime factors, or all the divisors of a number? 6 is a divisor of 72, just not a prime one, right?

Comment: @WillNess 9 is just implicitly included. For this purpose we are only examining [1, N/2]

Comment: @WillNess I kind of want the entire factor list to be the only predicate that returns true. so `factors(72, [6])` should be false, and `factors(72, [1,2,3,4,6,8,9,12,18,24,36])` would be true. Any thoughts?

Comment: to do this efficiently is not a trivial task in any language, not that I'm aware of. The usual way is to find prime factorization {p_i,k_i} and generate the factors from it.

Comment: @WillNess Well right now it works in the sense that if I do `factors(9, L)` `L` will be `[1,3]`, but `factors(9,[1])` still returns true

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14273559/prolog-get-the-factors-for-a-given-number-doesnt-stop/14288853#14288853

Comment: @false That wasn't the problem I was trying to solve. My program already ended normally.

Comment: @false could you clarify please, does this early unification problem relates to the steadfastness that you always mention? can we say that postponing the unifications makes it steadfast? Or is it "monotonic"?

Comment: @WillNess: The original def. is not steadfast because `factors(9, [1])` succeeds, but `factors(9, L), L = [1]` fails. So "output" arguments should be always steadfast. Monotonicity (in the sense of monotonic logic) is not directly related to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's why `factors(9,[1])` is true: the timing of attempted instantiations (that is to say, unifications) is off:

```
f_list(S,E,[])    :- S > E // 2, !.
f_list(S,E,[S|T]) :- divides(S,E), !, S1 is S+1, f_list(S1, E, T).
f_list(S,E,L)     :- S1 is S+1, f_list(S1,E,L).

%%  flist(1,9,[1]) -> (2nd clause) divides(1,9), S1 is 2, f_list(2,9,[]).
%%  flist(2,9,[])  -> (3rd clause) S1 is 3, f_list(3,9,[]).
%% ... 
%%  flist(5,9,[])  -> (1st clause) 5 > 9 // 2, !.
```

because you pre-specify `[1]`, when it reaches 3 the tail is `[]` and the match with the 2nd clause is prevented by this, though it *would* succeed due to `divides/2`.

The solution is to move the unifications out of clauses' head into the body, and make them only at the appropriate time, not sooner:

```
f_list(S,E,L) :- S > E // 2, !, L=[].
f_list(S,E,L) :- divides(S,E), !, L=[S|T], S1 is S+1, f_list(S1, E, T).
f_list(S,E,L) :- S1 is S+1, f_list(S1,E,L).
```

The above usually is written with the if-else construct:

```
f_list(S,E,L) :- 
  ( S > E // 2   -> L=[]
  ; divides(S,E) -> L=[S|T], S1 is S+1, f_list(S1, E, T)
  ;                          S1 is S+1, f_list(S1, E, L)
  ).
```

Also you can simplify the main predicate as

```
%% is not defined for N =< 0
factors(N,L):- 
  (  N =:= 1 -> L=[1]
  ;  N >= 2  -> f_list(1,N,L) 
  ).
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I use a somewhat simpler looking solution:

```
factors(1,[1]):- true, !.
factors(X,[Factor1|T]):- X > 0,
 between(2,X,Factor1), 
 NewX is X // Factor1, (X mod Factor1) =:= 0,
 factors(NewX,T), !.
```

This one only accepts an ordered list of the factors.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple enumeration based procedure.

```
factors(M, [1 | L]):- factors(M, 2, L).
factors(M, X, L):- 
   residue(M, X, M1), 
   ((M==M1, L=L1); (M1 < M, L=[X|L1])),
   ((M1=1, L1=[]); (M1 > X, X1 is X+1, factors(M1, X1, L1))).

residue(M, X, M1):-
  ((M < X, M1=M);
   (M >=X, MX is M mod X, 
     (MX=0, MM is M/X, residue(MM, X, M1);
      MX > 0, M1=M))).
```